# Need help with second derivative test

Tags: optimization

In an optimization problem with restrictions, when I have already found the critical points of a function and I have to classify those points (they can either be maxima or minima or saddle points), do I have to analyze the hessian matrix of the objective function or the hessian matrix of the lagrangian function?

Comment: You have to analyze the Hessian of the Lagrangian evaluated at pairs $(x,\lambda)$, $x$ critical point, $\lambda$ Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: The critical points that I deal with are conformed by two variables; according to what you say the hessian that I have to construct is a 3x3 matrix with the third element of each row being a second degree derivative with respect to λ, did I get it right?

Comment: It is the matrix in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of two variables it is simple. Let your Lagrangian be
$$ \mathcal{L}=f(x,y) + \lambda(g(x,y)-c) $$
You construct the following matrix ([the bordered Hessian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian)) for the critical Lagrange point:
$$ H=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & g_x & g_y \\
g_x & f_{xx}+\lambda g_{xx} & f_{xy}+\lambda g_{xy} \\
g_y & f_{yx}+\lambda g_{yx} & f_{yy}+\lambda g_{yy} \end{array}\right] $$
If $\det H>0$ then it is a maximum, if $\det H<0$ then it is a minimum.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to do it? I don't understand wikipedia's explanation

Comment: @Werther updated.